# Python3.8: The last output file is not stored properly on disk

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, flush

I have a global dataset at about 300m resolution in tif. I want to upscale it to 9km resolution (below you see my code). I decided to do upscaling piecewise due to high resolution data and large computing time. So I divided the whole global data into 10 pieces, do upscaling and store each piece separately in a tif file again. NOW my problem pops up: the last piece of global data is NOT saved completely on the disk. Each piece of map should be 2M but piece#10 is 1.7M. And the strange thing is that after running my script twice, that piece#10 will be completed and it will change from 1.7M to 2M. But the current piece10 is again not complete.

```
import numpy as np
from osgeo import gdal
from osgeo import osr
from osgeo.gdalconst import *
import pandas as pd
#
#%%
#-----converting--------#
df_new = pd.read_excel("input_attribute_table.xlsx",sheet_name='Global_data')
listvar = ['var1']
number = df_new['data_number'][:]
##The size of global array is 129599 x 51704. The pieces should be square
xoff = np.array([0, 25852.00, 51704.00, 77556.00, 103408.00])
yoff = np.array([0, 25852.00])
xcount = 25852
ycount = 25852
o = 1   
for q in range(len(yoff)):
    for p in range(len(xoff)):
        src = gdal.Open('Global_database.tif')
        ds_xform = src.GetGeoTransform() 
        ds_driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('Gtiff')
        srs = osr.SpatialReference()
        srs.ImportFromEPSG(4326)
        data =src.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray(xoff[p],yoff[q],xcount,ycount).astype(np.float32)
        Var = np.zeros(data.shape, dtype=np.float32)
        Variable_load = df_new[listvar[0]][:]
        for m in range(len(number)):
            Var[data==number[m]] = Variable_load[m]
#-------rescaling-----------#
        Var[np.where(np.isnan(Var))]=0
        ds_driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('Gtiff')
        srs = osr.SpatialReference()
        srs.ImportFromEPSG(4326)
        sz = Var.itemsize
        h,w = Var.shape
        bh, bw = 36, 36  
        shape = (h/bh, w/bw, bh, bw)
        shape2 = (int(shape[0]),int(shape[1]),shape[2],shape[3])
        strides = sz*np.array([w*bh,bw,w,1])
        blocks = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(Var,shape=shape2,strides=strides)
resized_array=ds_driver.Create(str(listvar[0])+'_resized_to_9km_glob_piece'+str(o)+'.tif',shape2[1],shape2[0],1,gdal.GDT_Float32)      resized_array.SetGeoTransform((ds_xform[0],ds_xform[1]*bw,ds_xform[2],ds_xform[3],ds_xform[4],ds_xform[5]*bh))
        resized_array.SetProjection(srs.ExportToWkt())
        band = resized_array.GetRasterBand(1)
        zero_array = np.zeros([shape2[0],shape2[1]], dtype=np.float32)
        for z in range(len(blocks)):
            for k in range(len(blocks)):
                zero_array[z][k] = np.mean(blocks[z][k])
        band.WriteArray(zero_array)
        band.FlushCache()                    
        band = None
        del zero_array
        del Var
        o=o+1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, you should either be sure to call `close` on a file, or use the `with` statement. However, it looks like neither of those is supported by `gdal`.

Instead, you're expected to remove all references to the file. You're already setting `band = None`, but you also need to set `src = None`.

This is a bad, non-Pythonic interface, but that's apparently what the Python gdal library does. In addition to being a weird gotcha in its own right, it also interacts poorly with exceptions; any unhandled exceptions may also result in the file not being saved (or being partly saved, or being corrupted).

For the immediate problem, though, adding `src = None` or `del src` should do the trick.

PS (from comments): Another option would be to move the body of the `for` loop into a function; that will automatically delete all the variables without you having to list them all and potentially miss one. It'll still have problems if there's an exception, but at least the normal case should start working...

Comment: I guess go through and do all the other variables until it starts working 
`del ds_xform, ds_driver, data` and so on. This is not a fault with your code, this is a fault with the `gdal` library.

Comment: Another option would be to move the body of the `for` loop into a function; that will automatically delete all the variables without you having to list them all and potentially miss one.

Comment: Thanks a looooooot. The problem is solved by your trick. At the end of the loop, I deleted ALL variables which are used during the loop for computation: `del src` , srs, zero_array, Var, srs, src, band, resized_array, strides, blocks. Then all pieces are properly stored on the disk even piece#10 :D